# logging in jar which is in classpath of a different project not working

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, log4j

I've a project A which has a jar in it's classpath with some utilities in it. 
Now both project A and classes in jar use log4j for logging and have log4j.properties file to control the output to log.

Now I'm not getting any logs from the logging statements in the jar. Not sure why it's happening. Is there a specific way or configuration which I need to take care of to make logger work for both the project A and the jar in it's classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys it was a silly mistake. The framework was not executing the file which had the logging statements as the listener was missing in testng suite which is a must for testng to invoke that.